# Group Data by month and week according to count and filter in chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have the following data set and I am using chart.js

```
<script>

       let chart = new Chart(mychart, {
            type:'line',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Issues',
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,255,0.4)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255,0,255,0.4)',
                    data: [{
                        x: new Date(2018, 4, 1),
                        y: 20
                    }, {
                        x: new Date(2018, 10, 3),
                        y: 17
                    },{
                        x: new Date(2019, 0, 1),
                        y: 20
                    }, {
                        x: new Date(2019, 0, 3),
                        y: 17
                    },{
                        x: new Date(2019, 2, 7),
                        y: 17
                    }, {
                        x: new Date(2020, 1, 1),
                        y: 20
                    }, {
                        x: new Date(2020, 3, 3),
                        y: 17
                    }, {
                        x: new Date(2020, 4, 1),
                        y: 20
                    }, {
                        x: new Date(2020, 5, 3),
                        y: 17
                    }, {
                        x: new Date(2020, 7, 1),
                        y: 20
                    }, {
                        x: new Date(2020, 9, 3),
                        y: 17
                    }, {
                        x: new Date(2020, 10, 5),
                        y: 28
                    }, {
                        x: new Date(2020, 11, 4),
                        y: 11
                    }]
                }],
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'time',
                        time: {
                            unit: 'month',
                            unitStepSize: 1,
                            distributions: 'series',
                            displayFormats: {
                                'day': 'DD/MM/YYYY'
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            } 
        })
```

The chart currently look like this:

[image]

What I want is whenever user selects the filter either month or week from the drop down the above data should be grouped accordingly to the count for week or month in the chart.
For example we have total 20 + 17 entries for January 2019 but they are coming as separate points what I want is it should be shown like 37 for January 2019.